# Where I can get my access token/key for the API?

Tags: support, api

I am designing an application where I only run it on my PC, it uses StackExchange's API 2.2

The problem is that during testing and troubleshooting my code, many of the 300 requests quota have been spent, leaving only half of them, which is insufficient.

I decided to use a Key/Access Token or whatever to access 10k keys

**How/Where I can get my key?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

API key management is handled over on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/). [See the sidebar](https://stackapps.com/questions/4831/my-registered-apps-are-not-showing-in-my-profile-where-can-i-find-them) for the relevant links, including the one to [register a new application](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register).

Answer (score 16):

There are two distinct objects:

- application key, which grants you 10000 queries/day instead of 300
- access token, which grants you access to a specific user's private information (and enables acting on behalf of the user).

It seems that right now, you need the application key and not a token. As Tim Stone wrote, you get it by registering your application at https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register.  If the field "OAuth Domain" is not  applicable to your case, put stackexchange.com there.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying how to fill OAuth Domain.